# How to create an FS under SunOS?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, solaris-zones

So there is a global zone, and we need to create an FS on a non-global zone. Also we need the new FS in a new DG/Volume inside the DG of the zone (if we see it from the global zone). How to do it? Using vx. (Or at least an authentic howto needed :D )

Answer (score 4):

You create a file system under Solaris global zone with one of these commands.

- ZFS: `zfs create filesystem`
- UFS: `newfs /dev/rdsk/...`
- VXFS: `mkfs -F vxfs ... /dev/vx/rdsk/...`

You can then use zonecfg to make that file system visible in non global zones.

```
# zonecfg -z zone1
zonecfg:zone1> add fs
zonecfg:zone1:fs> set dir=/nonglobalzone/path
    zonecfg:zone1:fs> set special=/path/to/the/filesystem/you/just/created
    zonecfg:zone1:fs> set type=lofs
    zonecfg:zone1:fs> end
```